# Issues with importing vpython for anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, vpython

I try to import `vpython` into anaconda. It seems to work so far, but if I call 
`from visual import *` it gives me an error.

However, it does work when I type `from vpython import *` ,which is really weird since in all programs I only see the `from visual import *` command.

Now to the real problem: I can't draw graphs. I have to call `from visual.graph import *` but this does not work (`from vpython.graph import *` doesn't work either).

I am receiving the error below:

> ImportError Traceback (most recent call last) 
>    in () ----> 1  from visual
>   import *  ImportError: No module named visual

Comment: I believe that could be useful for the other users to share the error output of your tries.

Comment: thanks for the quick response!

Comment: the error output is: ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e32a8874fc19> in <module>()
----> 1 from visual import *

ImportError: No module named visual

Comment: I have no experience with vpython, but I believe that section "*Experienced Python / VPython user?  Try Jupyter VPython*" on http://vpython.org/ could help you

Comment: thanks, I read it a couple of times, but unfortunately it doesn't help me much :(

Answer (score 0):

The `graph` functions now live in the main vpython library when using Jupyter. So,

`from vpython import *`

should be sufficient. (P.S. I'd recommend not importing * but rather importing the functions you plan to use or just `import vpython`.)

Note however that some functions change name in the Jupyter-compatible version of VPython, so `display` becomes `canvas` and `gdisplay` becomes `graph`, and you have to explicitly use `vector(x,y,z)` rather than `(x,y,z)` and have to use `obj.pos.x` rather than `obj.x`